# Как повернуть объект так чтоб он не проходил сквозь объекты которые ему мешают повернуться а просто останавливался

Tags: unity3d

Мне нужно повернуть объект, но если ему будет что-то мешать то он остановится чтоб не проходил сквозь коллайдер объекта который мешает ему.

RotateTowards - не подходит, потому что он проходит сквозь коллайдер.

Пример кода:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles.y, 0), _speed);
_rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
```

Comment: Возможно вам нужно это: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html

Answer (score 0):

Максим Фисман
Здравствуйте, MoveRotation - поворачивает как я и писал, но если он будет пытаться повернуть объект каждый кадр то объект будет скользить по поверхностям а это мне не подходит.

Текущий код:

using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody), typeof(CharacterController))]
public class PlayerRotation : PlayerInputs
{
[SerializeField] private float _speed;

```
private Camera _camera;
private Rigidbody _rigidbody;
private CharacterController _characterController;
private bool _isStopRotation;

private void Awake()
{
    _camera = Camera.main;
    _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    _characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

private void Update()
{
    if (_photonView.IsMine == false)
        return;

    bool isNowCharacter = _characterController.enabled;
    bool isRotate = Shift;

    if (isRotate == true && isNowCharacter == false)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, _camera.transform.eulerAngles.y, 0), _speed);
        _rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
        _isStopRotation = false;
    }
    else if (_isStopRotation == false)
    {
        _rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;
        _isStopRotation = true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).